# Fetching latest value from database even when there are no rows present

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm trying to fetch a points table for users to add points in by garnering their total points and adding it with the installation points, however by trying to fetch their "latest" points, new users who do not have an existing row in the table will throwback an error **"InvalidArgumentException; Data Missing"**. This would be my code below, and are there any other ways around this?

```
$currentpoint = Points::where('user_id', $input['user_id'])->latest()->first();
        $points['user_id'] = $input['user_id'];
        $points['points_add'] = $battery['point_installation'];
        $points['points_subtract'] = 0;
        $points['points_total'] = $currentpoint + $battery['point_installation'];
        $points['points_source_id'] = 1;
        $points['created_at'] = $mytime;
        $points['updated_at'] = $mytime;
$point = Points::create($points);
```

Comment: Can you specify what exactly is  inside  $battery['point_installation'];.

Comment: You are try to store instance in `points_total` column using `$points['points_total'] = $currentpoint + $battery['point_installation'];` it should be  `$points['points_total'] = $currentpoint->points_total + $battery['point_installation'];`

Comment: @ArunP $battery['point_installtion] stores the points per installation on a specific battery. it returns a valid int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$currentpoint = Points::where('user_id', $input['user_id'])->latest()->first();` of your code return an object and you are try to perform math (addition) operation on that object which is not possible. You can update your code like below.

```
$currentpoint = Points::where('user_id', $input['user_id'])->latest()->first();

        $points['user_id'] = $input['user_id'];
        $points['points_add'] = $battery['point_installation'];
        $points['points_subtract'] = 0;
        if($currentpoint != null)
        {
         $points['points_total'] = $currentpoint->points_total + $battery['point_installation'];
        }
        else {
          $points['points_total'] = $battery['point_installation'];
         }

        $points['points_source_id'] = 1;
        $points['created_at'] = $mytime;
        $points['updated_at'] = $mytime;
$point = Points::create($points);
```

Comment: there were two fixes to this;
1) i added the if condition for `$currentpoint` like you mentioned above;
`if($currentpoint != null)
        {
         $points['points_total'] = $currentpoint->points_total + $battery['point_installation'];
        }
        else {
          $points['points_total'] = $battery['point_installation'];
         }`
and 2;
i changed `$points['created_at'] = $mytime;
        $points['updated_at'] = $mytime;`
to 
`$points['created_at'] = Carbon::now();
        $points['updated_at'] = Carbon::now();`